# Java Heapdump - jsm <pid> -all GC.heap_dump

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, heap-dump, jcmd

There is no -all option for jcmd command as per documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

1. execute jcmd with -all option. GC is not triggered and can not see  [Full GC (Heap Dump Initiated GC) in GC logs.
2. execute jcmd with -all option. GC is triggered and can see  [Full GC (Heap Dump Initiated GC) in GC logs.

Is there any specific behaviour with -all option and not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Apparently, your are not referring to a general `jcmd` option but an option to the specific `GC.heap_dump` command option. Try `jcmd 0 help GC.heap_dump`…

Comment: Hi @Holger please post this as answer. This is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get help on a jcmd (sub)command, use “help command”, but note that you still have to specify a pid to meet `jcmd`’s formal command line pattern, i.e.

```
jcmd 0 help GC.heap_dump
```

which prints

```
GC.heap_dump
Generate a HPROF format dump of the Java heap.

Impact: High: Depends on Java heap size and content. Request a full GC unless the '-all' option is specified.

Permission: java.lang.management.ManagementPermission(monitor)

Syntax : GC.heap_dump [options] <filename>

Arguments:
        filename :  Name of the dump file (STRING, no default value)

Options: (options must be specified using the <key> or <key>=<value> syntax)
        -all : [optional] Dump all objects, including unreachable objects (BOOLEAN, false)
        -gz : [optional] If specified, the heap dump is written in gzipped format using the given compression level. 1 (recommended) is the fastest, 9 the strongest compression. (INT, 1)
```

<sup>(tested with JDK 17.0.2+8)</sup>